# How can i run two commands exactly at same time on two different unix servers?

Tags: shell, unix

My requirement is that i have to reboot two servers at same time (exactly same timestamp) . So my plan is to create two shell script that will ssh to the server and trigger the reboot. My doubt is

- How can i run same shell script on two server at same time. (same timestamp)
- Even if i run Script1 &; Script2. This will not ensure that reboot will be issued at same time, minor time difference will be there.

Comment: How precise does that timestamp needs to be? Minutes, seconds, milliseconds?

Comment: schedule a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job on both servers?

Comment: What's wrong with just keeping ntp running on both servers and use a cron job on both servers?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it remotely, you could use a terminal emulator with broadcast input, so that what you type is sent to all sessions of the open terminal. On Linux **tmux** is one such emulator.

The other easiest way is write a shell script which waits for the same timestamp on both machines and then both reboot.

Comment: comment on suggestion: provided that the local time of both machines is sufficiently accurate, e.g. synced by ntp

Comment: This will not work as both machines can have different timestamps and both undergo daily installation and other operation. Probably assing a cronjob that will ssh to both machine and triger reboot might be corect solution.

Answer (score 0):

- First, make sure both machine's time are aligned (use the best implementation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol and your system's related utilities).
- Then,

  - If you need this just one time: on each servers do a
    `echo /path/to/your/script | at ....`
    (`....` being when you want it. See `man at`).
  - If you need to do it several times: use `crontab` instead of `at`
    (see `man cron` and `man crontab`)